# ELK stack pulling in older logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am still newish to the ELK (elasticsearch, logstash kibana) stack and I am having some issues with making the logs that i want to show up in kibana.

What I am seeing is an older unrelated log.

I see it when i run with elastic search in embedded mode or running a standalone elastic search.

When i run it using out put to the standard out , it is the logs that i would expect, but then when i look at it on kibana its the older not even related logs.

I have tried deleting the since db file and still no help.

Is there an extra file that I may have to delete that caches the indices?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Edit: Here is my logstash conf.

```
input 
{ 
    file 
    { 
        path=> ["/Users/me/logs/m1/2014-05-21/consumer/bp1standalone2-0/*"] 
        sincedb_path => "./sincebb.xxx" 
        start_position => "beginning" 
    } 
} 

filter
{
    grok
    {   
        patterns_dir => "../patterns"
        match => [ "message", "%{CONSUMERLOGPARSER}" ]
    }
}
output 
{ 
    elasticsearch 
    { 
        embedded => true 
    } 
}
```

Comment: it looks like there is some type of cache that the elastic serch uses... i can not seem to track it down and clear it out.

Comment: Can't spot anything wrong. Have you tried to run logstash without your custom filter? Maybe your filter does not match your log file properly and skips the data?

Comment: when i run it just using stdout{} i get what i expect. but then when i run it with the elasticsearch , either with the standaolne isntance or embedded , it pulls up old files. even after i have renamed said files.

Answer (score 1):

There are no extra caches to delete, and it is the since db files which store the position in the log file which logstash has reached.  However, if the option start_position is "beginning" as you have it, the since db files are ignored and the file is processed from the start.